# A/C not working trouble shooting

Tags: ac, nissan, troubleshooting

So, my Nissan Rogue 2011's A/C stopped working, I've been trying to diagnose it, the blowers are fine but it's blowing room (engine) temp air.

I've checked:

- 10A compressor fuse(fine, 0 Ohms)
- The compressor wiring(got power)
- Compressor(it might have stopped for safety reasons, the reason I know is because I hardwired it and ran it for 2 secs not to damage it)
- Pressure on Low Side is high either on or off(understandably since the compressor is not firing)

However, I used one of those "engine light" monitors, and it had a cross on the "Evap" var.
[image]

I would like to know how to go about troubleshooting the evaporator, all I could find was compressor DIY but no evaporator's DIYs

Comment: Evap is for evaporator canister (emissions), nothing to do with AC.

Comment: You will need a set of freon gauges to check the freon charge.

Comment: @Moab could I rent a gauge set? I pretty short on cash

Comment: Not sure if you can, check your local parts stores.

Comment: Low side with compressor off should be at least 55-60psi.

Comment: Actually, if the system has set for a while without the compressor running, both the high and low side should be the same pressure because it will equalize. Also, you get get a gauge set from HF or eBay for cheap, which work just fine to help you diagnose what's going on. And like Moab stated, the EVAP mentioned on the OBDII has to do with fuel, not A/C. You do need to pay attention to this because it will NOT pass emissions with this being lit ... if yours is a location which worries about it. Realistically, it is probably low on charge and therefore the compressor won't kick on. Just a guess